# Robolectric nullpointer exception on imageview

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to write a simple unit test in ROBOLECTRIC. When i try to do something like:

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(new Activity());
```

i get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:146)
    at android.view.View.__constructor__(View.java:3269)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3252)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
```

what is going on? how can getApplicationInfo return null?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are creating new Activity instead using current, it should be something like this:

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
```

or

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
```

or

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(getApplication());
```

---

Getting activity example from [robolectric/RobolectricSample](https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs/views/LoadingTextViewTest.java)

```
Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class).create().get();
```

So it will be:

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(activity);
```

Comment: are you sure you're using Robolectric? how'd you get an activity reference?

Comment: thanks for the update, but what you gave was exactly what initially tried and that's how i got the null pointer (which was why i was curious)

Comment: if you don't believe me, try it yourself

Comment: but upvote for a nice attempt :) thanks for looking into this anyhow

Comment: you were using 'new Activity()', not 'activity' created by robo. So it doesn't work?

Comment: great minds think alike - i had initially tried all 3 of your ways before posting this question. the weird thing is that for most views in robolectric, you can just use `new Activity()` as the parameter. but for some reason, `ImageView` seems different

Comment: feel free to take a look at my answer if you run into the same problem.

Comment: so you should mark/tick your answer as "the one" :)

Comment: stackoverflow dictates that the original poster wait 3 days before accepting his/her own answer *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait.

@Simple Plan had an answer earlier that gave a hint (not sure why you deleted your answer). apparently in the newer version of robolectric you can only use:

```
    Context context = Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
    mSubject = new ImageView(context, mock(AttributeSet.class));
```